# C++ standard layout and reinterpret cast of first member

Tags: c++

Looking at cppreference (the de facto human readable form of the c++ standard), [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_standard_layout) in the section describing std::is_standard_layout, under Notes it says:

> A pointer to a standard-layout class may be converted (with reinterpret_cast) to a pointer to its first non-static data member and vice versa.

But this seems to contradict strict aliasing rules.  Can anyone point me to the parts of the c++ standard that support this Note on cppreference?

Comment: Not pointing to the standard, but consider that the aliasing rules have no problem if there really **is** an object of the correct type at the converted pointer address.

Comment: All this says is that `std::reinterpret_cast<...>&a` is equivalent to `&a.first`. Aliasing rules already cover that a pointer to `a.first` may alias the `first` in a pointer to `a`.

Comment: @BoP: That’s not a sufficient condition: you need pointer interconvertibility to have obtained a correct pointer value (not just one with the same address).